# How can I find out where CancellationToken is being cancelled?

Tags: c#, .net, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have a very weird case where my ASP.NET Core Web API endpoint fails randomly due to `CancellationToken` being cancelled. I have that problem only when I run integration tests, the API works completely fine when I call it from Postman.

In order to understand what's going on, I'd like to know what causes the `CancellationToken` to have its state set to cancelled. Is there any way to enable some logging for that or any other solution?

The `CancellationToken` comes from the ASP.Net Core Web API action, it's created by the framework iteself.

// EDIT

Here's my action:

```cs
        public async Task<ActionResult<TokenResponse>> GetToken(
            [Required][FromBody] Parameters parameters,
            ApiVersion apiVersion,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken) { ... }
```

My application just passes that token through various layers.

Comment: What CancellationToken are you talking about? One provided by a CancellationTokenSource created in the application code? One provided by the runtime in a Blazor Page? Or a hosted service? It the application creates the CTS, it's the application that calls Cancel. In a HostedService it's probably because the application is shutting down.

Comment: It's a token created by the framework itself. My app is just an ASP.net Core API. I added this info to the question.

Comment: So it's a controller action, not just a cancellation token provided by the framework. That means the request died for some reason, eg the client broke the connection. It doesn't matter how or why, you need to abort the call because nobody's going to receive that response

Comment: As a sidenote -  in my experience cancelation quite often happens due to exceeding timeout, which can happen due to multiple reasons - for example you are trying to hit a wrong address, the request is processed too long and caller cancels it (i.e. integration test client).

Comment: When you added that CancellationToken to the signature you *explictily told ASP.NET Core* that you want to cancel the request when the client aborts for whatever reason. If you don't want that, remove the CancellationToken parameter

Answer (score 4):

From pure technical standpoint you can leverage cancelation callback (if you are the owner of `CancellationTokenSource` do not forget to call `TryReset` on it in case it is reused). For example:

```cs
CancellationToken cancellationToken = ...;
cancellationToken.Register(() => throw new Exception("Here")); // exception with stack trace will be thrown
```

Though not sure that this information will be as useful as you possibly expect.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the framework reuses the same `CancellationTokenSource` for multiple requests? Registering callbacks repeatedly on the same long-life source, could result in a memory leak.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias 1) I would be a bit surprised but am not ready to claim that it can't 2) the main OP goal is temporary monitoring for  some issue in test so it should not be a big problem. Though it is a completely valid point. Actually AFAIK something like that happened in `Sql.Client` which has introduced a memory leak in one of the latest versions - see [github](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1810).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Also I hope that if ASP.NET reuses the token it calls `TryReset` which should clear the registrations.